# Why i can not change flushmode in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-orm

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write
>   operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn
>   your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker
>   from transaction definition.

I tried to change it in code and in xml to another `flushmode`  but it is still Auto.

```
hibernatetemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession().setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);
```

and `<prop key="org.hibernate.FlushMode">COMMIT</prop>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i solved it

```
final Person object = new Person(id, name, password);
    hibernateTemplate.execute(new HibernateCallback<Person>() {

        public Person doInHibernate(Session session)
                throws HibernateException {

            session.save(object);
            session.flush();
            return object;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your operations, some of them being persiting or updating entities, on the session are not within a transactional context.

Try to enclose them within:

```
Session session = hibernatetemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTrasaction();

...

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Now, when you begin the transaction, the flush mode should be implicitly set to COMMIT/AUTO.

Comment: actually i solved it  

     hibernateTemplate.execute(new HibernateCallback<User>() {

            @Override
            public User doInHibernate(Session sn) throws HibernateException {
                sn.save(user);
                return user;
            }
        });

Answer (score 1):

you can make hibernateTemplate object and override excute method